# User defined grasp pose for pick task

Tags: ros, pr2, ros-kinetic, grasp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am  quite satisfied with the grasp generator that MoveIt task constructor offers, but I wanted to know if and also how it would be possible to define a custom grasp pose instead of a generated one for a pick task.

Normally you would do this stage to create a pick :

```
{
    // grasp generator
    auto grasp_generator = std::make_unique<stages::GenerateGraspPose>("generate grasp pose left");
    grasp_generator->setAngleDelta(M_PI/4);
    grasp_generator->setPreGraspPose("left_open");
    grasp_generator->setGraspPose("left_close");
    grasp_generator->setMonitoredStage(current_state);

    auto grasp = std::make_unique<stages::SimpleGrasp>(std::move(stage));
    grasp->setIKFrame(Eigen::Affine3d::Identity(), "l_gripper_tool_frame");
    grasp->properties().configureInitFrom(Stage::PARENT);
    grasp->setMaxIKSolutions(10);


    // pick container, using the generated grasp generator
    auto pick = std::make_unique<stages::Pick>(std::move(grasp));
    pick->setProperty("eef", "left_gripper");
    pick->setProperty("object", std::string("object"));
    pick->properties().configureInitFrom(Stage::PARENT);

    geometry_msgs::TwistStamped approach;
    approach.header.frame_id = "l_wrist_roll_link";
    approach.twist.linear.x = 1.0;
    pick->setApproachMotion(approach, 0.01, 0.10);

    geometry_msgs::TwistStamped lift;
    lift.header.frame_id = "base_footprint";
    lift.twist.linear.z =  1.0;
    pick->setLiftMotion(lift, 0.05, 0.10);
    current_state = pick.get();
    t.add(std::move(pick));
}
```

If I understand well, the grasp generator find possible grasp, these information are given to "SimpleGrasp" that assemble them with IK and gripper movement (in a serial container), then "Pick" is a serial container that compile previous information with approach and lift moves, right ?

I thought that I would need to generate a pose with "GeneratePose" stage (and also set the pregrasp and grasp property "manually") and then give it to "SimpleGrasp" but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea on how I could use a custom grasp pose instead of using the grasp generator ?

Thanks in advance for the help,

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354738/user-defined-grasp-pose-for-pick-task/) by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) on 2020-06-16**:
I found that I would need to carry all of the "open gripper, approach, close gripper, attach object" manually in a serial container. It seems to work but is there any cleaner/compact way to do this ?

**Comment by [timtuch96](https://answers.ros.org/users/75708/timtuch96/) on 2021-07-28**:
Could you maybe post your solution, as I am currently also struggling to use the task constructor without generating the grasps?

**Comment by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) on 2021-07-29**:
I finally managed to add custom poses, you can find the stage here : https://github.com/YannickRiou/moveit_task_constructor/blob/master/core/src/stages/generate_custom_pose.cpp

You can then use it by giving it an array with custom poses (please see the function createDropTask that use the stage "GenerateCustomPose") : https://github.com/YannickRiou/pr2_mtc/blob/4b6242d05bad952ac7b6d3f2df7e7a5df6f0afdb/src/pr2_tasks.cpp#L329

Feel free to ask question if something is unclear.

**Comment by [timtuch96](https://answers.ros.org/users/75708/timtuch96/) on 2021-07-29**:
Thank you very much, I will try it out asap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally managed to add custom poses, you can find the stage here : https://github.com/YannickRiou/moveit_task_constructor/blob/master/core/src/stages/generate_custom_pose.cpp

You can then use it by giving it an array with custom poses (please see the function createDropTask that use the stage "GenerateCustomPose") : https://github.com/YannickRiou/pr2_mtc/blob/4b6242d05bad952ac7b6d3f2df7e7a5df6f0afdb/src/pr2_tasks.cpp#L329

Feel free to ask question if something is unclear.

---

Originally posted by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) with karma: 114 on 2021-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2